# How can I force a MySQL table to become corrupted?

Tags: linux, mysql, monitoring, nagios, corruption

I have written a simple [Nagios](http://nagios.org/) plugin that calls [mysqlcheck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) (which checks for corrupted tables) and will give a warning if any are corrupt.

However none of my tables are corrupt now. So I'm not 100% sure that my plugin is working fine. I have a dev server that's not misson critical. How can I force one (or any) of the tables there to be corrupt so that I can test my nagios alert?

For the record the server is Ubuntu Dapper and the mysql is version 5.0

Comment: interesting.......

Comment: Assuming they're MyISAM tables I'd imagine you could just open a window. A slight breaze should be enough to cause those ACID free tables to crash, tip over and catch fire ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can't back up the databases by copying them from /var/lib/mysql and then copying them back because they get corrupted, you have to use mysqldump instead.

So if you go into one of the folders for the database in /var/lib/mysql, ie /var/lib/mysql/myDB/ and mess with some of the files that ought to do it :-)

So I would recommend copying one of the files, editing a little with a hex editor, and copying it back.

Answer (score 9):

```
cat DB1.myd /dev/random > DB2.myd
```

Comment: I like this one!

Comment: Won't that keep pulling data from /dev/random until my harddisk fills up? :P

Comment: Hey, you said corrupt, right? ;-)

Comment: Rory, Ya, but just hit Ctrl-C at some point

Comment: Rory, Or use head /dev/urandom, to a file and then cat  those

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
cat /dev/urandom > yourdb.myd
```

Comment: That will keep going till my harddisk fills up.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a fuzzing tool like [zzuf](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/zzuf) to fuzz a preexisting database file, e.g.

```
zzuf < good.myd > fuzzed.myd
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that a more realistic way to simulate fault would be to pull the rug out from beneath MySQL's feet while it's performing an intensive update. Issuing SIGKILL to the `mysqld` process should be sufficient. Chances are that when you restart MySQL the table(s) in question will be marked as crashed.

Alternatively I'd suggest applying other people's suggestions but to the `.MYI` indec file rather than the data file.

Answer (score 2):

example:

```
mysql> repair table Transactions;
^CQuery aborted by Ctrl+C
+-----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
| Table                             | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text              |
+-----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
| test.Transactions | repair | error    | 137 when fixing table |
| test.Transactions | repair | status   | Operation failed      |
+-----------------------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (17.84 sec)

mysql> select * from Transactions limit 1;
ERROR 144 (HY000): Table './test/Transactions' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps a command execution that does something like the following:

```
echo "aaa" > file.myd
```